# RegEx to accept only years like this form YYYY/YYYY/YYYY from 1900 to 2019

Tags: html, regex, validation, separator

I have input in my form HTML, and i want to control the year typed must be in this form :
 YYYY OR YYYY/YYYY/YYYY/YYYY/YYYY ...ect
my pattern is :

First test :

```
pattern="^((19)\d{2}\/|(20)[0-1][0-9]\/)+"
```

Second Test:

```
pattern="^((19)\d{2}\/?|(20)[0-1][0-9]\/?)+"
```

I expect for exemple 2018/2019/1999 but i must type 2018/2019/1999/ for the first test
But if i test with the second:
this form is accepted but i don't want to be accepted : 20182019/1999

Comment: what about `^(\d{4}\/|(\d{4}$))+` ?

Comment: `pattern="^(?:19\d{2/|20[0-1][0-9])(?:\/(?:19\d{2/|20[0-1][0-9]))*"`

Comment: https://regex101.com/ you can test and create customs regex using this site

Comment: ^((19)\d{2}\/|(20)[0-1][0-9]\/|(19)\d{2}$|(20)[0-1][0-9]$)+ this works for me .
Thank you @Bobbey

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep it short, use a word-boundary `\b`:

```
pattern="(\b/?(19\d\d|20[01]\d))+"
```

Notes:

- the html pattern attribute describes a full string, `^` and `$` are implicit, no need to write them.
- `/` isn't a special character, no need to escape it.
- `[0-1]` doesn't make sense since there's nothing between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

The second regex should be

```
pattern="^((19)\d{2}\/|(20)[0-1][0-9]\/?)+"
```

instead of

```
pattern="^((19)\d{2}\/?|(20)[0-1][0-9]\/)+"
```

whose question marks after forward slashes mean the match is optional.

Comment: No, your regex can accept this :1999/1999/20162016 but i dont want it

Comment: Oops, didn't see the second question mark ('optional quantifier')..edited answer

Answer (score 0):

This is want i want Problem Solved:

```
^((19)\d{2}\/|(20)[0-1][0-9]\/|(19)\d{2}$|(20)[0-1][0-9]$)+
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
pattern="^(?:19\d{2/|20[0-1][0-9])(?:\/(?:19\d{2/|20[0-1][0-9]))*"
```

**Explanation:**

```
^                       # beginning of line
  (?:                   # start non capture group
    19\d{2}             # 1900 --> 1999
   |                    # OR
    20[0-1][0-9]        # 2000 --> 2199
  )                     # end group
  (?:                   # start non capture group
    \/                  # a slash
    (?:                 # start non capture group
      19\d{2}           # 1900 --> 1999
     |                  # OR
      20[0-1][0-9]      # 2000 --> 2199
    )                   # end group
  )*                    # end group, may appear 0 or more times
$                       # end of line
```